# FoxPro: Append arbitrary number of views into a single view or table

Tags: sql, visual-foxpro, foxpro

I have several views which I need to combine into a single view or table.  The views all have the same structure and are titled `view_1`, ..., `view_x`.

I've had the best luck with the following.  I can get the total number of views in the database, so I have just used `12` here for simplicity.  The code creates a new view called `test` and populates it with the contents of `view_1` as expected.  No errors are thrown when executed.  In the status bar, I see that it has processed XXXX records.  This corresponds to the last view (`view_12`).  However, `test` only contains the contents of `view_1`.

```
create sql view test as;
select * ;
from view_1 

for i = 2 to 12
    insert into test ;
    select * ;
    from view_&i. 
endfor
```

Am I missing something simple or is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't really treat views like tables unfortunately - they are just stored SQL statements. So to create a new view with the results of other views you essentially need to build a new SQL statement based on the SQL statements of the other views.

Note this assumes that the schema for each smaller view is the same, as you said :

```
Close All
Clear All
Clear

Open Database mydatabase Excl

lnViews = Adbobjects(laViews, "VIEW")

If Ascan(laViews, "vcombined") > 0
    Delete View vcombined
Endif

lcSQL = ""

* -- You'll probably find out the view count and put it here.
For lnView = 1 to 3

    lcView = "view_" + Transform(lnView)
    lcSQL = lcSQL + Iif(lnView > 1, "union ", "") + DBGetProp(lcView, "View", "SQL")

Endfor  

Create SQL View vcombined as &lcSQL
```

Comment: This definitely works, however, "union " should be  " union ".  There needs to be a space before and after the word.  Otherwise it generates a keyword error.  It also gives me a "too many unions" error.  In VFP8 this is `Error 1834: The maximum number of UNIONs (10) has been exceeded.`

Comment: You need Visual FoxPro 9 in that case, which has no practical limit.

Comment: As an aside, I know that VFP recommends using Hungarian notation.  The documentation has a page specifically about naming conventions.  However, it only gives "c" for "character", "n" for "number", etc.  I notice you use "lc", as in 'ell-see'.  Is the ell for "long"?  Or something else?

Comment: L for declared local. Just house style where I work.

Answer (score 0):

A VFP View is simply an SQL definition + some properties saved in the DBC. You could combine multiple views with same structure into a new view simply by using a "union ALL". However, it wouldn't be much realistic to have it as a single view as it wouldn't make sense to make it updatable.

Using those views to create the new one doesn't make much sense really. Instead you could directly use one view's SQL definition to create the final view. ie: If your view definitions are:

```
select CustomerId, CustomerName from Customers1
select CustomerId, CustomerName from Customers2
*...
select CustomerId, CustomerName from CustomersN
```

Then you could simply have your new definition as:

```
create sql view vMultiple as ; 
select CustomerId, CustomerName from Customers1 ;
union all ;
select CustomerId, CustomerName from Customers2 ;
union all ;
* ... ;
select CustomerId, CustomerName from CustomersN
```

To add some indirect updatability to this, you might want to add a column for the source like:

```
create sql view vMultiple as ;
select 1 as Source, CustomerId, CustomerName from Customers1 ;
union all ;
select 2 as Source, CustomerId, CustomerName from Customers2 ;
union all ;
* ...   ;
select N as Source, CustomerId, CustomerName from CustomersN
```

Since creating such a view doesn't make much sense, you might instead want to create it as a cursor when needed:

```
select 1 as Source, CustomerId, CustomerName from Customers1 ;
union all ;
select 2 as Source, CustomerId, CustomerName from Customers2 ;
union all ;
* ...   ;
select N as Source, CustomerId, CustomerName from CustomersN ;
into cursor crsMultiple ;
nofilter   && or readwrite if it needs any updating
```

Remember, both cursors and views (also a cursor) do not have persistent indexes and view cursors are buffered. You would create your index(es) as needed.

Think twice, why you need a view for this (or any view).